# Expand object properties based on a single model attribute (Stock tracking app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, stockquotes

I am trying to build a little web application with Ruby on Rails. It's a simple tool to track stocks that people are interested in.

For the stock data I am using the [stock_quote gem](https://github.com/tyrauber/stock_quote).

Currently, I have a model with a single field, 'ticker'. Here people would enter the ticker symbol of the stock they're interested in watching. I want to be able to populate a table of information based on the ticker when the user logs in (full company name, price etc). When I test my current method, I get a " uninitialized constant Target::StockQuote" error. However, when I call my methods get_current_price or get_company_name in the console, they work perfectly. I know I need to keep my views dumb, but I'm not sure how to make it more simple than this- and have them work properly.

I would like to be able to populate my dashboard table with information on the stocks users are watching. Given that the model stores the ticker (i.e. AAPL), I need to somehow input the ticker into a series of methods in the model that pull the proper data from the stock_quote API and return the result to my HTML table.

Thanks for the help

[Full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/dJ2xWd5G)

**stock.rb**

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ticker

def get_company_name(ticker)
  company_name = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).company
end

def get_current_price(ticker)
  company_name = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).last
end
end
```

**stocks_controller.rb**

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController

 def dashboard
  @stocks = Stock.all
 end 

end
```

**dashboard.html.erb**

```
<tbody>
    <% @stocks.each do |stock| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= stock.get_company_name(stock.ticker) %></td>
        <td><%= stock.stock %></td>
        <td><%= button_to "Delete", edit_target_path, :class => "btn btn-small btn-danger" %> </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please post a full stacktrace of your exception and information about what you are trying to do

Comment: Where does `edit_target_path` come from. Can we see the class for this and the routes file because you say you are getting `uninitialized constant Target::StockQuote` error but there is no `Target` class.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your button to point at the `stock` object and tell it the action & method for that action are `delete`.

```
<td><%= button_to "Delete", {:action => "delete", :id => stock.id }, :method => :delete, :class => "btn btn-small btn-danger" %></td>
```

Please see: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Or, I think this syntax is nicer:

```
<td><%= link_to "Delete", stock, :method => :delete, :class => "btn btn-small btn-danger" %></td>
```

**Bonus**

You've got an inefficiently written Stock class. Since you're calling instance methods, you don't need to pass the `ticker` value to `get_company_name` and `get_current_price`. The instance methods are operating within the context of a specific Stock object already, so they already know what the value for `ticker` is. That's what it means to call the method on `stock` in your view, ie `stock.company_name`.

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ticker

  def company_name
    StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).company
  end

  def current_price
    StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).last
  end
end
```